# footer border not displaying in browser

Tags: html, css

In this school project I want the border to surround the entire "wrapper" div, including the footer.

I've applied a border to the div id="wrapper", parent of the footer, and it does not display as expected in a browser (no border around footer). When I set my cursor on the "wrapper" selector in CSS, the footer is not highlighted (my text editor does this in chrome) which goes to reason why the border does not apply to footer.

My desire is to fix this problem and understand what caused it. Link to page below:
http://timc-projects.com/final-project-V3/index.html

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 85%;
    min-width: 869px;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ACACAC;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
footer {
    height:85px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #1a2447;
}
.footer-nav {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 22px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    font-size: small;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}
li{
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 15px;
}
li a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", "Helvetica Rounded", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
.footer-p {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial, verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;
    font-style: italic;

}
```

Comment: Remove `height: 1000px` on the wrapper, you have too much content for the set height. Also please remove the "cursive" font, it's so very ugly

Comment: Ha ha, thanks Zach. I caught my mistake and was coming back to delete my question but you are quick on the draw!

Comment: Zach, question: Were you visiting my site on a mobile device? The default font was cursive but I hadn't looked at it, now I need to find something that works when "Brush Script MT" doesn't work.

Comment: No, I am viewing on a desktop with a fairly large screen. You should just load Brush Script from a more reliable source or have it hosted yourself (: